# Implementation of abstract class without template argument

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I want to implement two simple abstract classes like so:

```
class Hashable {
public:
    virtual Int hashValue() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Equatable {
    virtual Bool operator == (const T& other) = 0;
}
```

These classes will give me the opportunity of partial template specialization in my new dictionary class.

However, I could not make them to work. Here is the declaration of my dictionary class:

```
template <Hashable Key, typename Value>
class Dictionary {
     .
     .
     .
};
```

The problem is, key should also be `Equatable` because hashability should require it.

So, I have two questions:

1. Can we rewrite `Equatable<T>` class to have no template arguments? Does C++ have any keyword referring to current type of the class?
2. In my opinion, `Hashable` had better inherit from `Equatable` class. How to achieve this without new template definition on `Hashable` (if my first question is answered yes, this is already solved then)?
3. What would be the best object-oriented approach here? To have an interface class with template arguments seems tacky.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're actually looking for typeclass mechanism, which is not really nicely available in C++. There is a mechanism of concepts that was planned since C++11, but it didn't make it even to C++17 (http://honermann.net/blog/?p=3)

Answer (score 2):

What you're basically looking for is Concepts, with which you'd write something like:

```
template <class T>
concept bool Hashable()
{
    return requires(T t, T u) {
        {t.hashValue()} -> size_t;
        {t == u} -> bool;
    };
}

template <Hashable Key, class Value>
class Dictionary {
    ...
};
```

But that won't even be in C++17.

Until then, we can write this sort of thing in C++14 using `void_t`:

```
template <class...> using void_t = void;

template <class T, class = void>
struct Hashable : std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct Hashable<T, void_t<
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::declval<T&>().hashValue(), std::size_t>::value>,
    decltype(std::declval<T&>() == std::declval<T&>())
    >>
: std::true_type { };

template <class Key, class Value>
class Dictionary {
    static_assert(Hashable<Key>::value, "Key must be Hashable<>");
    ...
};
```

Note that in both cases, we're requiring the `Key` type to have this functionality - we're not requiring the `Key` to *inherit* it virtually. This is far more efficient. No virtual dispatch necessary.

> What would be the best object-oriented approach here?

To not use an object-oriented approach.

Comment: Does latest clang have concepts, or do you know when it'll be available?

Comment: @Leviathlon It's unclear when (if *ever*) concepts will be in the C++ standard. gcc 6.0 on trunk has the only implementation I'm aware of.

Comment: FYI, the whole idea is derived from https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Hashable_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe that

```
template <Hashable Key, typename Value>
```

does not actually do what you expect it to do. Consider:

```
template <int Key, typename Value> class x{};
```

now, you can instantiate `x<1, int>` and `x<2, int>`, but these are not merely different objects, but different *types*. So, in your case, your `Hashable` object would become part of the type (so it would have to be generated during compilation, not at runtime).

What you most probably want instead is - like Wojciech Frohmberg mentioned in the other answer:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Dict {
...
static_assert(std::is_base_of<K, Hashable>::value, "Only Hashable can be the key);
}
```

or `enable_if` or some other template magic included from `type_traits`.

What you're looking for are concepts, that didn't even make C++17, or typeclasses (available in other languages, like Haskell or Scala)

If you really want to use object-oriented approach here, go for something like:

```
template <typename Value> 
class Dict {
    Dict(std::shared_ptr<Hashable>, Value) 
    {}
}
```

However, it's not a typical implementation, so I wouldn't recommend it

Comment: Is it possible to specialize a template argument with two base classes (i.e. `template <Hashable, Equatable Key, typename V> ...`) ?

Comment: these are not base classes - this is what your type arguments are. Your example defines a template with three arguments: one of type Hashable, one of type Equatable and one arbitrary. You seem to be mimicking Haskell's typeclass syntax - it doesn't work this way in C++. if you want to impose base-class dependency or existence of an arbitrary method in a template argument, you have to use `type_traits`. By using `type_traits` you can write arbitrary amount of contraints.

Comment: Of course I didn't want to define a template with three arguments, my example was just to show what I want to do. Thank you, anyway.